# How to bootstrap the Maven versions plugin?

Tags: maven, version

Our project X has a dependency Y. We would like to use the Maven versions plugin to update Y to the latest available version.

We have no problem when the version of Y is set and valid (e.g.: to 2).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
    <version>2</version>
</dependency>
```

We run `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` and the version of Y is updated (e.g.: to 3).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
    <version>3</version>
</dependency>
```

However we are not sure how to bootstrap the process. Initially we have no idea what might be a valid version of Y. If we specify an invalid version (e.g.: 12345) we get the following error.

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact group:Y:pom:12345 in <repo> (<http://repo-url/path>)
```

This is a real problem. We receive Y from another team. The Maven repository through which they deliver their artifacts contains their latest 10 releases (e.g.: 132-142).

We could bootstrap the process manually, but it would not scale with the tens of dependencies we have in practice.

**Potential solutions**

We could not implement any of these solutions. They are listed in order of preference. Any thoughts?

- Is there a way to run the versions plugin without downloading any of the dependencies from the pom.xml?
- Is there a way to read the latest version of a dependency (versions plugin, other plugin). We could then update the pom.xml outside of Maven.
- Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Vanishing release versions are a problem if you use Maven because it is usually assumed that released versions are not deleted (Build stability).

If you have no influence on the team for artifact Y that deletes their old artifacts, you should think about having a Nexus/Artifactory as a proxy in between. There, you can keep all the versions that you ever used for your build so that you do not run into the problems described in your question.

Comment: Valid answer. However probably not in the spirit of what we'd like to set up. We'd like to trade repeatability (e.g.: keeping lots of old artifacts) for fixability (e.g.: ability to create/deploy new artifacts fast).

Comment: We use SNAPSHOT versions for development, so that there is no need to update every time a change happens. Have you thought about using SNAPSHOT versions? Or is there a special reason you only want release versions?

Comment: This is a good idea. However we prefer to not use SNAPSHOT versions so that we can unambiguously refer to any of the versions created so far. When we inspect a build the dependencies versions might no longer be available, but we know exactly what they were and contained at the time.  I'm now implementing custom scripts to do what the versions plugin would do if it worked.

Comment: You can do that, but be aware that deleting release versions means that they may or may not be available in certain local repositories and builds might work and break unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes, this is a good advice. We are aware of this. We have a script to discover the latest versions and modify the POMs accordingly: we can recover from the issue you mention. Using SNAPSHOTs would solve the problem by providing a version no matter what, but its contents would be untraceable. This is worse for our use case.